# Extracting the value of an attribute with a hyphen using Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, attributes, screen-scraping

I am traversing through my  tags using beautifulsoup 4.  I have the following tag contents and am unable to extract the atttribute value of the 'data-event-name' attribute.  I want '15:02' from this.

[This is the html I need to extract 15:02 from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yooOo.png)

I have tried many many things but am unable to get this value.  I tried using the re package, getattr python, find, find_all, etc, etc.  this is one example of something I tried:

```
for racemeetnum,r1_a in enumerate(r1, start=1):
    event1 = getattr(r1_a, 'data-event-name') # doesnt work
```

<

Comment: Can you post the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Jack Fleming.  I managed to sort this last night.  In the end my issue wasn't that I couldn't find the attribute, it was that I wasn't trapping the errors when the attribute wasn't found.  I surrounded code with a try/except and it worked fine.

Thanks for responding!